# Rounded Corners in Parent DIV not effecting Child DIVs

Tags: html, css, hierarchy, rounded-corners

So, I'm experimenting with using rounded-corners in CSS3 (not in IE, don't care if it works there), and I have the DIV where all of my content lives looking quite nice.  The problem I'm having is that there are child DIVs that are not getting "masked" by the parent's rounded corners.  I'm not looking for the child to inherit the rounded-corners.  I just want to have any content inside the parent to not be visible where it is rounded, as if it were masked.  I tried using "overflow: hidden;", but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Does anyone have any ideas how the children of the rounded-cornered container DIV can be sorta masked by the parent DIV?  If it's of any use, I'm using "position: absolute;" on the parent DIV.  Not sure if that will make any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: try using padding-top and padding-bottom on the div.

Comment: Overflow: hidden works in chrome

Comment: I doubt there's an exact, direct solution.  But, if you could provide a little more detail, there is probably a way to achieve the effect you are going for.  What kind of content are you trying to mask?  Can you post some example code?

Answer (score 20):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element. This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use padding on the div.  If you make the padding equal to the radius you shouldn't have to worry about any overlap or the content appearing in the rounded areas.

```
<style>
.round{
border-radius:10px;
padding:10px;
background-color:red;
}
</style>

<div class="round">Rounded Corners</div>
```

Here is a helpful site that talks all about the CSS3 Border Radius: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/.

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining this correctly. I want the child DIV to appear masked under one of the corners of the parent.