# Child breaking out of parent rounded corners in Safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari, rounded-corners

This is my problem: I want to make a parent div round using ronded corners, and I want a child of that element (with a colored background) to remain square, but I don't want the corners of the square to point outside the round parent. This is not that difficult to fix in most browsers, I simply add overflow:hidden to the parent and *viola*. But, in Safari that fix does not work - the square corners of the child points out of the round parent. So my question is, is there a way to get rounded corners on a parent to affect a child in Safari?

There are two obvious workarounds, but none of them applies in this case:

- The child must fill up the entire space of the parent, so adding a
  padding to the parent (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277403/rounded-corners-in-parent-div-not-effecting-child-divs)) is not an option.
- Neither can I add rounded corners to the child since the child is resized by javascript and used as a status indicator, and therefore needs to be square.

Here is a jsFiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/4Lnbt/

This is the result in Chrome (left) and Safari (right):

[image][image]

**Update:** I'm running Safari 5.1.7 in both OS X and Windows, same result.

Comment: There's some known bugs with this https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72619

Comment: Oddly enough, I get the left result in Safari 6.

Comment: As mentioned above, this used to be a known but in several browsers. Add the version of Safari and your OS to the description...

Comment: Added Browser and OS in update above.